# How to drive an 100 mA forward current LED using STM32H743 Microcontroller to the collector without using external power supply?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, stm32, power-electronics

I am new to electronics hardware so kindly help me and give me suggestions.

I am working on STM32H743 microcontroller for dual camera interface and LED interface.

The total current of my STM32H743 Nucleo board is 500 mA in that both the cameras and microcontroller consumes 450 mA of current, so there is only 50 mA left to drive an LED (forward current 100 mA).

I am planning to drive an LED using PWM signal from the microcontroller using an NPN transistor.

Since I have only 50 mA left for supply current, I'm not able to drive my LED (forward current 100 mA).

Is there any solution for it?

Please find my circuit below:

[image: partial schematic]

Comment: Did you try to choose a resistor to limit the current to 50mA? The LED will probably still be quite bright, maybe bright enough for your application.

Comment: Most of the circuitry doesn't actually run on not 5V, but on 3.3V, or even lower voltages. Pretty sure there are linear voltage regulators to get the 3.3V (or other voltages) from the 5V. Disabling the linear regulators, and using switching regulators instead, will enable you drastically lower the nucleo+camera modules power requirements, and give you enough headroom for your LED. But honestly, I don't think doing that will be any easier/cheaper than just using the appropriate supply.

Comment: What is the reason of the overall current limit?  What do you know about the mechanism enforcing that?  Is this for personal use or for others to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LEDs still work well when driven below their rated current.  So if you only have 50mA, you can set the current limiting resistor in your circuit so that the current is only 50mA.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply . my total current it self is 50 mA because the rest of the current is been used by the cameras. What if instead of 100 mA forward current LED i am using multiple LEDs (5 LEDs) with forward current of 20 mA each so total 100 mA for 5 LEDs. is it possible ti get good illumination . kindly help me

Comment: @Muthu If you put the 5 LEDs in series, then they will not work off a 5V supply - that would need over 15V.  If you put 5 LEDs in parallel then you are just sharing the current you have available.  5 x 20mA is still more than the 50 mA you have available.

Comment: Yes i will be connecting it in Parallel only but the problem is it takes 100 mA. but i have only 50 mA is there any way to drive all the LEDs. or is there any seperate LED Driver circuit which taking 50 MA of and drives the LEDs of 100 mA

Comment: or Is there any modifications that we can do in the circuit by adding some components so that we can achieve the results.

Comment: @Muthu Note your question is like: Can you buy a $100.000 car with full accessoires with $50.000 of money? Simon B answered: you can still buy it for $50.000 if you lower the demands (in this example: leave out some assecoiseres) The car will still drive. Likewise: a 100mA LED will still shine with 50 mA, but less bright.

Comment: @Muthu If you've only got 50mA, then you've only got 50mA.  There's no magic circuit that will turn it into 100mA.  You don't have enough voltage "spare" to run a buck converter to drive the LED using a lower voltage and higher current.

Comment: Yeah I Perfectly Understood. Thank you so much Simon

Answer (score 1):

- Try to reduce the power consumption of the microcontroller/camera's.
- Use a switched power supply to convert 5V to 3.3V to drive the LEDs.
  In case of 95% efficiency, this would give you a little higher current of 72mA. (5V*50mA = 90%*3.3V*72mA)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply . 50mA is the Maximum current left in my circuit rest of the current has been consumed by microcontroller and cameras.Is there any solution to drive 100 mA LED using 50 mA of Current. Kindly Help me Thank you.

Comment: @Muthu You are repeating the same question. I could repeat the same answer... Could you please clarify what part you don't understand?

Comment: The thing is i have only 50 mA of current left to drive one 100 mA LED or five 20mA LEDs(Parallel) So i cant understand how we can get 72 mA of current if i have only 50 mA left  . Kindly help me sir

Comment: When using a very efficient DC DC converter, you can convert 5V to 3.3V. If you have 50mA spare at 5V, this is 5V * 50mA = 250mW. So, with a 100% efficient DC DC converter you can convert this 250mW of power to 3.3V, with about 75mA (because 3.3V * 0.75mA = 250mW). With less efficiency, you will end up with less output current. 95% will give about 72mA at 3.3V. But you will never reach the 100mA. Because the LED needs 3.3V * 100 mA = 330mW, while you are only feeding it with 250 mW.

Comment: I Understood Huisman thank you so much